# Incompatible pointer type during function call

Tags: c, pointers, function-call

I have reduced my code to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void change_data (char *data);

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char data[20] = {0};

    strcpy(data, "This is a test.");
    change_data(&data);

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void change_data (char *data)
{
    printf("%s\n", data);
}
```

I want to be able to change the main variable in the function.  I thought that using `&` means sending the address rather than copying the data.  But I get the following error when I compile:

```
tt.c: In function 'main':
tt.c:13:14: warning: passing argument 1 of 'change_data' from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
  change_data(&data);
              ^
tt.c:5:6: note: expected 'char *' but argument is of type 'char (*)[20]'
 void change_data (char *data);
      ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Can someone show me what I'm doing wrong, because I don't have a clue.  Ty.

Comment: The error message is telling you very clearly what you're doing wrong.  The type `char (*)[20]` is rather clearly different from `char *`.  What you presumably don't recognize yet is that `char (*)[20]` is a 'pointer to an array of 20 `char`'.  Just using the plain array name converts `data` into a `char *`; using the `&` converts it into a different type altogether — a pointer to array.  Don't use pointers to arrays where you want pointer to the zeroth element of the array.  Consider using `&data[0]`, or just use `data`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `&`. `data` has type `char[20]`, so a pointer to it has type `char (*)[20]`. An array will *decay* to a pointer type when it needs to do so, so simply passing `data` will pass it as `char*`.